# Array to nested Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to convert some data into a json. The data looks like this:

```
$one = ["ID","Name","Address1","Address2"];
$two = ["KJS0001","Mike","Cairo","Egypt"];
$three = ["KHO0001","Jhon","Paris","France"];
```

The Output I want to get is:

```
{
  "KJS0001":{
    "Name":"Mike",
    "Address":["Cairo","Egypt"]
  },
  "KHO0001":{
    "Name":"Jhon",
    "Address":["Paris","France"]
  }
}
```

Since the amount of nested attributes varies and its indexed with id also how to make Address (contain data from address1 and address2 array). Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly will vary? The no of variables like it can be $three, $four..etc? Or the no. of parameters id, name etc?

Comment: base on parameters id and it nested to name, address (address1 and address2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible solution, By creating new array and use `json_encode`

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    //$columns = ["ID","Name","Address1","Address2"];
    $data[] = ["KJS0001","Mike","Cairo","Egypt"];
    $data[] = ["KHO0001","Jhon","Paris","France"];
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $value){
      $result[] = [$value[0] => ["Name"=>$value[1],"Address"=>[$value[2],$value[3]] ] ];
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Column name, you mentioned in `$one` is not needed if columns are fixed.

Live demo : https://eval.in/621908

Output is :

```
 [ 
   {"KJS0001":{"Name":"Mike","Address":["Cairo","Egypt"]}},
   {"KHO0001":{"Name":"Jhon","Address":["Paris","France"]}}
 ]
```